# Is it possible to declare a val before assignment/initialization in Scala?

Tags: scala, initialization, declaration, lazy-initialization

In general, can you declare a val in scala before assigning it a value? If not, why not? An example where this might be useful (in my case at least) is that I want to declare a val which will be available in a larger scope than when I assign it. If I cannot do this, how can I achieve the desired behavior?

And I want this to be a val, not a var because after it is assigned, it should NEVER change, so a var isn't ideal.

For example:

```
object SomeObject {
    val theValIWantToDeclare // I don't have enough info to assign it here

    def main(): Unit = {
        theValIWantToDeclare = "some value"
    }

    def someOtherFunc(): Unit {
        val blah = someOperationWith(theValIWantToDeclare)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
object SomeObject {
  private var tviwtdPromise: Option[Int] = None
  lazy val theValIWantToDeclare: Int = tviwtdPromise.get
  private def declareTheVal(v: Int): Unit = {
    tviwtdPromise = Some(v)
    theValIWantToDeclare
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    declareTheVal(42)
    someOtherFunction()
  }

  def someOtherFunction(): Unit = {
    println(theValIWantToDeclare)
  }
}
```

It will crash with a `NoSuchElementException` if you try to use `theValIWantToDeclare` before fulfilling the "promise" with `declareTheVal`.

Comment: This looks like it will fix my issue! One question, what does the:
    theValIWantToDeclare
    ()
do in the private def function? Don't you just need the tviwtdPromise = Some(v) line?

Comment: There's also `Promise`.

Comment: @MichaelBlankenship you definitely should force `theValIWantToDeclare` to evaluate the value right now by using it in statement position. Otherwise you could "redeclare" it multiple times, and each time, it would override the hidden `tviwtdPromise` value. The `()` in the very end is just to make clear that `Unit` is returned. It's not needed, actually, I've removed it.

Comment: @som-snytt Yes, but AFAIR it requires some strange imports with default executor pools etc. I decided that adding `Promise` into the mix would be more confusing rathen than more "DRY".

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I cannot thank you enough for the solution as well as answering my second question. Great explanations! Thank you! :)

Comment: I think you are wrong about Promise. You can create a Promise and complete it arbitrarily. Instead of your helper method, you would just `promise.complete(Try(42))`. It's an interesting question when to prefer a Promise; it depends on who supplies the result. Also worth noting that Mr Blankenship looks like fommil in his formal wear, or fommilwear.

Comment: @som-snytt Ok, yes you are right: no need for executor pools to create a Promise. But still: it would require importing lot of stuff like `scala.concurrent.Promise` and `Try`, and then in order to extract the value one would also need `Future`, and then call `value` on it (which I consider somewhat of a code-smell), and then unpack the whole `Option[Try[T]]` that `value` returns... Seems like a bit too much `import`-overhead for a simple single-threaded write-once variable. On look: needs more peak lapels for full fommilwear 8-]

Comment: fommil is definitely peak lapel.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you need a `lazy` val.

A `lazy` val is populated on demand and the result is cached for all subsequent calls.

https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/02/lazy-vals-scala-look-hood/

Comment: The problem is lazy doesn't help me because I don't have "some value" at declaration time. So, I don't have the 'expression' which would execute when the val is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not define a `SomeObjectPartial` that is partially constructed, and `class SomeObject(theVal)` that takes the value as a parameter?

Then your program has two states, one with the partial object, and another with the completed object.